# get_serving_url returns object of type 'Key' has no len()

Tags: google-app-engine

I'm trying to return a thumbnail from a blobstore. For the full image, I normally write out

```
<img src='img?img_id=%s'></img>" % greeting.key()
```

(where greeting is in a loop getting a selection of images from the database) with a handler `('/img', ImageHandler)` and function

```
class ImageHandler(webapp.RequestHandler):
def get(self):
    greeting = db.get(self.request.get("img_id"))
    if greeting.picture:
        self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = "image/png"
        self.response.out.write(greeting.picture)
    else:
        self.error(404)
```

This works great. However, when using get_serving_url, calling

```
<img src='img?img_id=%s'></img>" % (images.get_serving_url(greeting.key(), 32))
```

I get a `TypeError: object of type 'Key' has no len()`. I can only assume the blob key I used is incorrect, but as far as I know, that *is* the blob key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want to call `str()` on the key object before passing it to `get_serving_url()`. It's most likely expecting the string form of the key.

The reason it worked in your original version is because using the `%` operator with a `%s` format specifier automatically calls `str()` for you to determine the string to interpolate in.